# Update a 1 Row 1 Column with Multiple Values

Tags: laravel

i've some problem with my code.

```
$id = DB::table('sn_project_details')->insertGetId([
            'emp_name' => $request->emp_name,
            'emp_id' => $request->emp_id,
            'department' => $request->department,
            'submit_date' => $request->submit_date,
            'total_amount' => $request->total_amount,
            'project_tittle' => $request->project_tittle,
            'project_desc' => $request->project_desc,
            'scope' => $request->scope,
            'file' => $request->file
            ]);
//Update Table 
\DB::table('sn_project_details')
      ->where('project_id', $id)
      ->update(['doc_ref' => "ID_",$request->scope,"_",$id]);

return redirect('/user')
```

I want to update column doc_ref with example value **ID_Scope_220**, 
ID_ its fixed value. Scope from textbox scope. 220 from @emp_id. 
but when i execute this code, update query not working properly.
can someone help? thx

Comment: in update query it should be `$request->emp_id`

Comment: So on update's `where('emp_id', $emp_id)` why are you using `$emp_id` which is your `id` of the recently inserted row via `insertGetId `. Either use `where('emp_id', $request->emp_id)` or `where('id', $emp_id)`. Unless `emp_id` is your `IDENTITY` column. Let me know your schema of `sn_project_details ` and I will post an answer below.

Comment: sorry i missed my code, not `$emp_id` but  `$id` is getting from `insertGetId`.
my table `IDENTITY` is `project_id`

Comment: Are you getting any errors or else what issue are you facing? Please post that.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `sn_project_details` set `doc_ref` = ID_, `0` = SN, `1` = _, `2` = 38 where `project_cd` = 38)

Comment: use dot instead of comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use dot instead of comma

```php
->update(['doc_ref' => "ID_".$request->scope."_".$emp_id]);
```